# How would I programmatically click a button in JavaFX from another method?

Tags: java, button, javafx

I have a listener class that is networked into my phone to receive input from an application called TouchOSC. In that class, I can call methods whenever I press a button on my phone. What I need to do is to click a JavaFX button to trigger an event in that method whenever my computer receives the input from my phone. How would I trigger something like that?

Answer (score 38):

[`button.fire()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Button.html#fire--)

> Invoked when a user gesture indicates that an event for this ButtonBase should occur.

When a button is fired, the button's [`onAction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ButtonBase.html#onActionProperty) event handler is invoked.

> The button's action, which is invoked whenever the button is fired. This may be due to the user clicking on the button with the mouse, or by a touch event, or by a key press, or if the developer programmatically invokes the fire() method.

*Sample Code*

Creates a button and automatically fires it four times.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class RapidFire extends Application {
    private static int nClicks = 0;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        // setup button and action handler.
        Button button = new Button("Click Me!");
        button.setOnAction(event -> {
            nClicks++;
            System.out.println("Clicked " + nClicks + " times.");
        });
        button.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        button.setPrefWidth(100);

        // show the button.
        stage.setScene(new Scene(button));
        stage.show();

        // fire the button a few times in succession.
        IntStream.range(0, 4).forEach(
                i -> button.fire()
        );
    }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Output of the sample is:

```
Clicked 1 times.
Clicked 2 times.
Clicked 3 times.
Clicked 4 times.
```

Comment: This does not work. Fire won't fire the Action event I set in the other method.

Comment: Works for me.  Unless I misunderstood your question, you probably have some other issue in your code which is preventing it from working as you expect.

Comment: @DylanLeeBlanchard: be careful to implement button.setOnAction(). I made mistake that I have implemented event handler on button.setOnMouseClicked().