JavaFX button setOnMousePressed not triggering with button.arm()
I am trying to replicate a "Push to talk" style button system in JavaFX. When you hold down a key on the stage, the button is activated and deactivated when you let go. As you can see from my example below, when you hold down the button and let go it prints out the correct action.
        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
        Button button = new Button("Push To Talk");
        stackPane.getChildren().add(button);
        Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane, 400, 200);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            String codeString = e.getCode().toString();
            if(codeString.equals("A")) {
                button.arm();
            };
        });

        scene.setOnKeyReleased(e -> {
            String codeString = e.getCode().toString();
            if(codeString.equals("A")) {
                button.disarm();
            }
        });

        button.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
            System.out.println("Push to Talk Activated!!");
        });

        button.setOnMouseReleased(e -> {
            System.out.println("Push to Talk Deactivated!!");
        });

However when I press the A key, the button graphic is being activated and deactivated but the button functions are not being called. What am i doing wrong?

did you try button.fire()?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29353909/2423906

button.fire() only fires the onAction() function which is a single click. I am after it being held down and released. I originally used a togglebutton but cant in my program

I am expecting button.arm() to be called when the button is held down and button.disarm() to be calledas button released. I want listeners elsewhere in the program when to be activated when arm() and disarm() are called. I also need listeners for mouse button pressed and released and key button pressed and released

I posted an answer assuming some requirements before reading this. But: "I am expecting button.arm() to be called when the button is held down and button.disarm() to be calledas button released.". They are called. Why do you think they are not called? "I want listeners elsewhere in the program when to be activated when arm() and disarm() are called. " So just use a listener on the armedProperty(). "I also need listeners for the mouse button pressed and released". Why? What else do you want to do when the button is specifically pressed that is different to arming/disarming the button?

I am assuming the requirements are that you want pressing and releasing the A key to mimic exactly pressing and releasing the button with the mouse, both in terms of the graphical appearance of the button and in terms of the event handlers invoked.
The button.setOnMousePressed/Released(...) handlers do exactly what their names suggest: they are invoked when the user presses or releases the mouse on the button. The button also registers handlers internally that set the armed and pressed state of the button, which result in the changes in appearance that you can mimic by arming and disarming the button in code.
If you want to invoke code when the button is armed, simply register a listener with the armed property instead of using a mouse handler:
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
        Button button = new Button("Push To Talk");
        stackPane.getChildren().add(button);
        Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane, 400, 200);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            String codeString = e.getCode().toString();
            if(codeString.equals("A")) {
                button.arm();
            };
        });

        scene.setOnKeyReleased(e -> {
            String codeString = e.getCode().toString();
            if(codeString.equals("A")) {
                button.disarm();
            }
        });

        //button.armedProperty().addListener((_, _, isArmed) -> {
        //    if (isArmed) {
        //        System.out.println("Hold to talk activated");
        //    } else {
        //        System.out.println("Hold to talk deactivated");
        //    }
        //});
        button.armedProperty().subscribe(isArmed ->
            System.out.println("Hold to talk " + (isArmed ? "activated" : "deactivated"))
        );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}

As noted in the documentation, armed is subtly different from pressed. If you press the mouse on the button, and move it off the button without releasing it, the button remains pressed but is no longer armed. If you want to maintain the "press to hold" state when it's pressed but no longer armed, for example, you could do something like button.armedProperty().or(button.pressedProperty()).addListener(...). You could also use an external style sheet to make the style when it's pressed the same as the style when it's armed if needed; but these requirements are not clear from the question.

Note that the above results in holding state about the application ("is hold to talk activated?") in a property for a UI element (the armed property for the button). This violates the normal separation of application state from the UI and will always lead you into trouble. (For example, if you decide later not to use a button at all but some other UI control, you could potentially need to change code anywhere in the application.)
A better approach is to properly model the state of the application, and use a BooleanProperty to represent the "hold to talk activated" state. In real life this property would go in a separate model class, but here is the basic idea:
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {

    private final BooleanProperty holdToTalkActivated = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        //holdToTalkActivated.addListener((_, _, isArmed) -> {
        //    if (isArmed) {
        //        System.out.println("Hold to talk activated");
        //    } else {
        //        System.out.println("Hold to talk deactivated");
        //    }
        //});
        holdToTalkActivated.subscribe(isArmed ->
            System.out.println("Hold to talk " + (isArmed ? "activated" : "deactivated"))
        );
        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
        Button button = new Button("Push To Talk");
        stackPane.getChildren().add(button);
        Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane, 400, 200);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        BooleanProperty aKeyPressed = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            String codeString = e.getCode().toString();
            if(codeString.equals("A")) {
                aKeyPressed.set(true);
            };
        });

        scene.setOnKeyReleased(e -> {
            String codeString = e.getCode().toString();
            if(codeString.equals("A")) {
                aKeyPressed.set(false);
            }
        });


        // mimic "armed" button appearance for button when hold to talk is active:
        PseudoClass active = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("active");
        holdToTalkActivated.subscribe(isActive -> 
            button.pseudoClassStateChanged(active, isActive)
        );
        // (in real life make this part of the external style sheet):
        scene.getStylesheets().add("data:text/css,"+"""
            .button:active {
                -fx-color: -fx-pressed-base;
            }
            """);

        // bind model state to UI:
        holdToTalkActivated.bind(button.armedProperty().or(aKeyPressed));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}

The functionality of this implementation is slightly different to the previous version (the behavior is different if you press the A key, press the button, and then release the A key with the mouse still pressed on the button) but the requirement for this scenario is not specified in the original post anyway.

Thankyou, however I am using Java 11, and it says to use unamed patterns i need to upgrade to Java 22+?

i think i fixed it by doing:         button.armedProperty().addListener((observableValue, aBoolean, t1) -> {
if (t1) {
System.out.println("Hold to talk activated");
} else {
System.out.println("Hold to talk deactivated");
}
});

@MarkUK Yes; unnamed patterns were introduced as a preview feature in Java 21 and as a full language feature in Java 22. Either upgrade or just name the parameters. There's really no good reason not to use the latest JDK in a standalone GUI application though.

@James_D Well, then why use addListener() when subscribe() is so much better.  Not even a preview feature.

@DaveB Because I was unaware it had been added :). I'll refactor when I get a chance.

@James_D The version that calls a Consumer taking just the new value triggers immediately. So you don't have to manually run that code to establish the initial value. Very cool.

@DaveB Yes indeed. A lot of this newer functionality (also ObservableValue.map and flatMap) is based on work that Tomas Mikula did in his EasyBind and ReactFX libraries. Those are worth taking a look out (mainly out of interest, as they are no longer actively maintained). There is quite a lot more functionality in there that could be incorporated into the main libraries.
